# A function to count words in a corpora using dictionary values using Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, counting, words

I'm a Python Newbie trying to get a count of words that occur within a corpora (corpora) using a dictionary of specific words. The corpora is a string type that has been tokenized, normalized, lemmatized, and stemmed.

```
dict = {}
dict ['words'] =  ('believe', 'tried', 'trust', 'experience')
counter=0
Result = []
for word in corpora:
    if word in dict.values():
        counter = i + 1
        else counter = 0
```

This code produces a syntax error on the dict.values() line. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a colon after `else`, and it's on the wrong indentation block

Comment: Off-topic : Don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: This may help you, What is value in "corpora".
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict ['words'] =  ('believe', 'tried', 'trust', 'experience')
>>> dict.values()
[('believe', 'tried', 'trust', 'experience')]

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't do `dict = {}`. `dict` is a built-in function and you are shadowing it. That's not critical, you won't be able t use if you 'll need it later.
2. A dictionary is a key→value mapping. Like a real dictionary (word → translation). What you did is said that value `('believe', …)`, which is a tuple, corresponds to the key `'word'` in your dictionary. Then you are using `dict.values()` which gives you a sequence of all the values stored in the dictionary, in your case this sequence consists of exacly one item, and this item is a tuple. Your `if` condition will never be `True`: `word` is a string and `dict.values()` is a sequence, consisting of a single *tuple* of strings.
3. I'm not really sure why you are using a dictionary. It seems that you've got a set of words that are important for you, and you are scanning your `corpora` and count the number of occurences of those words. The key word here is *set*. You don't need a dictionary, you need a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).
4. It is not clear, what you are counting. What's that `i` you are adding to the `counter`? If you meant to increment `counter` by one, that should be `counter = counter + 1` or simply `counter += 1`.
5. Why are you resetting `counter`?

   ```
   counter = 0
   ```

   I don't think you really want to reset the counter when you found an unknown word. It seems that unkown words shouldn't change your counter, then, just don't alter it.
6. *Notes.* Try to avoid using upper case letters in variable names (`Result = []` is bad). Also as others mntioned, you are missing a colon after `else`.

So, now let's put it all together. The first thing to do is to make a set of words we are interested in:

```
words = {'believe', 'tried', 'trust', 'experience'}
```

Next you can iterate over the words in your corpora and see which of them are present in the set:

```
for word in corpora:
    if word in words:
        # do something
```

It is not clear what exactly the code should do, but if your goal is to know how many times all the words in the set are found in the corpora all together, then you'll just add one to `counter` inside that `if`.

If you want to know how many times *each word* of the set appears in the corpora, you'll have to maintain a separate counter for every word in the set (that's where a dictionary might be useful). This can be achieved easily with [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) (which is a special dictionary) and you'll have to filter your corpora to leave only the words you are interested in, that's where [`ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) will help you.

```
filtered_corpora = itertools.ifilter(lambda w: w in words, corpora)
```

—this is your corpora will all the words not found in `words` removed. You can pass it do `Counter` right away.

This trick is also useful for the first case (i.e. when you need only the total count). You'll just return the length of this `filter`ed corpora (`len(filtered_corpora)`).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues. You did not define `corpora` in the example here. you are redfining `dict`, which is a built-in type. the `else` is not indented correctly. `dict.values()` return an iterable, each of which is a tuple; `word` will not be inside it, if word is a string. and it is not clear what `counter` counts, actually. adn what `Results` is doing there?

your code may be similar to this (pseudo)code

```
d = {'words' : ('believe', 'tried', 'trust', 'experience')} #if that's really what you want
counter = {}
for word in corpora:
    for tup in d.values(): # each tup is a tuple
        if word in tup:
            x = counter[word] if word in counter else 0
            counter[word] = x+1
```

There Is A Shorter Way To Do It.

This task, of counting things, is so common that a specific class for doing so exists in the library: [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).